# How to Reduce Multiple Repeating Lines of Tidyverse Code - for Multiple Charts with X by Different Y's - Using a Vector of Names

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Using the Iris dataset, the code below uses a tidyverse approach to create multiple charts and is ultimately what I want to achieve. However, it seems repetitive to write out the three lines for "gg1","gg2", and "gg3", so I'm attempting to rewrite this in a more efficient way. (See code below)

```
iris0 <- iris %>%  
group_by(Species) %>%  
nest() %>%  
mutate(
gg1 = map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()),
gg2 = map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()),
gg3 = map(data, ~ ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()),
g = pmap(list(gg1, gg2, gg3), ~ gridExtra::grid.arrange(..1, ..2, ..3))
)
```

Ignoring the final gridExtra part for now as well as the names (gg1, gg2,and gg3), below is an attempt to produce the three charts from the code above in one line of code by using a vector of names called Y. But this doesn't seem to work. I've tried a few other variants, but help would be appreciated...

```
Y<-c("Sepal.Width","Petal.Width","Petal.Length")

iris0<-iris%>%
group_by(Species)%>%
nest()%>%
mutate(
   map(data,~ggplot(.,aes(Sepal.Length))+geom_point(aes_string(Y))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reshaping and using different grouping variables may be the easier-to-follow approach here, but you can attempt something the lines you are currently working with using a double `map` loop to loop through each species and each y variable.

Don't forget to define the `y` argument when mapping to the y aesthetic in `geom_point`.  That will avoid at least some of the errors you are getting now.

I include code for sending the plots on to `grid.arrange`.

```
iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     nest() %>%
     mutate(graphs = map(data, function(x) {
               map(Y, function(y) ggplot(x, aes(Sepal.Length )) +
                                       geom_point( aes_string(y = y) ) )
               }),
          grid.graphs = map(graphs, ~gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = .x) ) )
```

You can add species names to the multiplots using the `top` argument, but I had to group the nested dataset for this to work.

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest() %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(graphs = map(data, function(x) {
        map(Y, function(y) ggplot(x, aes(Sepal.Length )) +
                geom_point( aes_string(y = y) ) )
    }),
    grid.graphs = map(graphs, ~gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = .x, 
                                                       top = grid::textGrob(Species) ) ) )
```

I find nested loops relatively difficult to follow.  A reshaping approach would take a fair amount more code, so ends up looking pretty complicated.  Essentially you make your dataset long, then `nest` on both species and the y variable prior to making the plots.

I ended up doing a second nest for the `grid.arrange`, which seems pretty convoluted.

```
iris %>%
     gather(variable, yvar, one_of(Y) ) %>%
     group_by(Species, variable) %>%
     nest() %>%
     group_by(Species, variable) %>%
     mutate(graphs = map(data, ~ggplot(.x, aes(Sepal.Length, yvar) ) +
                              geom_point() +
                              labs(y = unique(variable) ) ) ) %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     nest(graphs, .key = "graphs") %>%
     mutate(grid.graphs = map(graphs, ~gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = flatten(.x)) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, the double map loop is what I was looking for. The only thing is that is doesn't display the Species name in the charts. I didn't originally ask for that...but I may post it as another question.

Comment: Looks like if you group the nested dataset, you can add the species name as the title in `grid.arrange`.